# エラーの原因を教えてください SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Tags: python

このエラーの意味と改善の仕方を教えてもらえないでしょうか

[image]

Comment: スクリーンショットではなく、コードとエラーメッセージをそれぞれ文字のまま質問文に貼り付けてみてください。

Answer (score 2):

おそらく、`print("「{}」" .format(s))`の後ろに全角空白文字あたりが付いているのでしょう。
閉じ括弧`)`の後ろに文字があるようでしたら、削除してみてください。

それから、それを直しても、その行のインデントが無いように見えたりするので、意図通りにソースコードが入力されているか、よく確かめてみてください。